# PHP Laravel 5.7 Tymon/jwt-auth Not Installing

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, jwt

Trying to install the Tymon/jwt-auth package and work with it, following the directions on the site: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/ Doesn't seem like the publish configuration seems to do anything, I'm not seeing a config/jwt.php file, and the command `php artisan jwt:secret`doesn't do anything useful, saying that there are no commands defined in the "jwt" namespace.

Does anyone have any info on getting JWT working on Laravel 5.7?

Verified that it is in the composer.json:

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"
},
```

Comment: have you tried `composer dump-autoload`? if it didn't work, close and reopen the terminal, then rerun it, try `composer install` again.. it seems to  be a composer problem

Comment: and don't forget to check if it's added to  *composer.json* file or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice to get this released soon you can just using this

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
```

That worked for my project

Answer (score 2):

Go to `composer.json`. Add this to require: `"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0"`. Then run `php composer update`. The version of jwt 0.5 is not suported by carbon 2.0. This worked for me with laravel 5.8.